# Grab data from Google Analytics Dashboard in scala.js

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api, scala.js

I want to fetch data from google analytics dashboard into scalajs program. I tried using embed API from the following link :
    https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/getting-started

it is working fine. But I want the code to be done in scala.js rather than the javascript. 
Also, the data fetched by this is displayed in Charts. How can I get the data in simple tabular format so that I can store the values in some scala collections and use them later ?

Code :

```
<script>
(function(w,d,s,g,js,fjs){
g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(cb){this.q.push(cb)}};
js=d.createElement(s);fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics')};
}(window,document,'script'));
</script>
<script>
gapi.analytics.ready(function() {
var CLIENT_ID = 'my_client_id';
gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
container: 'auth-button',
clientid: CLIENT_ID,
});
var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
container: 'view-selector'
});
var timeline = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
reportType: 'ga',
query: {
  'dimensions': 'ga:date',
  'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
  'start-date': '30daysAgo',
  'end-date': 'yesterday',
},
chart: {
  type: 'LINE',
  container: 'timeline'
}
});
gapi.analytics.auth.on('success', function(response) {
 viewSelector.execute();
});
viewSelector.on('change', function(ids) {
var newIds = {
  query: {
    ids: ids
  }
}
timeline.set(newIds).execute();
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: What's the JS code you have come up with? What have you tried so far in Scala.js?

Comment: @sjrd I've also written the code now. Please check and I tried using `js.eval` function to load the library in scala.js. But it does not seem right way to do it.

Comment: why not use the google analytics APi directly? the embedded is mostly for display purposes https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/  I dont know scala so cant tell you if the google-apis-js-client works with it or not other wise you can just code it yourself.

Comment: @DaImTo I tried using google analytics java API but could not get any success.  It was showing error `Referring to non-existent class : GoogleNetHttpTransport` and same error with 'GsonFactory' also.

Comment: Google APIs Java client there should be some sample code for Java up on the documentation site

Comment: I've already tried the sample code given in their documentation.  But that didn't work. However, I used JavaScript Client API and it worked well. But still the coding is done in JavaScript. I am not from JavaScript background and that's why I am having some issues converting the javascript into scala.js.